# Telerik grid custom formatting based on multiple date ranges

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

At least 3 ways I can think of that this could be done:-

1st (ideal) - in a single telerik grid which has around 8 columns, 1st col would list all table entries with the next 6 for displaying different dates submitted for each entry but not all necessarily having a value for each entry, final col would link to each entry on a separate page to allow new dates to be submitted via datepicker or to be edited.

Main problem is I need to be able to display each of the dates on the grid in different colours depending on each col, by this I mean I record a date in 1st col of which has a yearly renewal so if >6months then it's colour 1, >1month colour 2, <1month colour 3 and finally if past 1 year mark then colour 4.

There are also 2 different possible renewal lengths for the other col's.

2nd - Each different renewal length would get its own grid so 1st for 1y, 2nd for 2nd length and 3rd for 3rd length.

3rd (likely) - 4 grids to replace the colours it would simply display each category so 1 grid would show all entries which had more than 6months, grid 2 would show greater than 1month, grid 3 would show less than 1month and grid 4 would show past time length.

I have no clue how best to sort the dates out in a way that would do what I need it to but I figure either option 1 will be possible or option 3 is the simplest.

Edit -

```
using System
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace (...).Models.DTO
{
    public class ...DTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //public string C1D
        //{
        //    get
        //    {
        //        if (C1D < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-183)) return "Green";
        //    }
        //}
        public string C1D
        {
            get
            {
                if ((C1D = DateTime.ParseExact(C1D, "yyyy/mm/dd", null)) < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-183)) return "Green";
            }
            set;
        }
        public string C2D { get; set; }
```

Here it shows how I have tried to setup C1D in 2 different ways and for C2D how I usually setup the cols which go into the telerik grid.

```
[GridAction]
    public ActionResult _List(int? Id)
    {
        List<...DTO> ret = new List<...DTO>();
        _db.(...).ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            ret.Add(new ...DTO
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.(...)Name,
                C1D = (x.C1SD.HasValue) ? x.C1SD.Value.ToShortDateString() : "",
                C2D = (x.C2SD.HasValue) ? x.C2SD.Value.ToShortDateString() : "",
```

This is how I would go about setting it up in the controller for displaying the data in the telerik grid.

Below is how I setup the view

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid<(...).Models.DTO.(...)DTO>()
   .Name("...List")
   .DataKeys(dk => dk.Add(x => x.Id))
   .Columns(c =>
       {
           c.Bound(x => x.Name);
           c.Bound(x => x.C1D)
               .Title("...");
           c.Bound(x => x.C2D)
               .Title("...");
           c.Bound(x => x.C3D)
               .Title("...");
           c.Bound(x => x.C4D)
               .Title("...");
           c.Bound(x => x.C5D)
               .Title("...");
           c.Bound(x => x.C6D)
               .Title("...");
           c.Bound(x => x.C7D)
               .Title("...");
       })
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataBinding(db => db.Ajax().Select("_List", "..."))
    .Render();
%>
```

Edit 2 -
I've also tried

```
.ClientEvents(e => e.OnDataBound("onDataBound"))

function onDataBound(e) {
    if (e.dataItem.C1D > DateTime.Today.AddDays(183)) {
        e.cell.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    if (e.dataItem.C1D > DateTime.Today.AddDays(30)) {
        e.cell.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    }
    if (e.dataItem.C1D > DateTime.Today) {
        e.cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    if (e.dataItem.C1D <= DateTime.Today) {
        e.cell.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
    }
```

}

and upon reaching this page it would break into code and say "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'dataItem.C1D' is null or not an object" and "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'cell.style' is null or not an object" and then display the page with all the dates in the grid so those items aren't null but is there otherwise some other code/format I should be using to perform this function?

And also looked at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/customformatting in regards to .cellaction like below

```
.CellAction(cell =>
{
    if (cell.Column.Title == "Title Name")
    {
        if (cell.DataItem.C1D > DateTime.Today.AddDays(183))
        {
            //Set the background of this cell only
            cell.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "background:red;";
        }
    }
})
```

and I had to change .Name to .Title since it didn't recognise .Name, but I get the error msg "Error   1   Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DateTime' " so seems I won't be able to perform this complex a task in a cell action.

I've also posted this on the telerik forums attached to another question but so far no reply
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/telerik-grid-row-custom-formatting-on-either-bit-int-string-field.aspx

Edit 3 -

Additional Controller code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using (Database Name).Models;
using (Database Name).Models.DTO;
using Telerik.Web.Mvc;
using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
namespace (Database Name).Controllers
{
    public class (Controller Name)Controller : Controller
{
(Database Name)Entities _db = new (Database Name)Entities();
public ActionResult List()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

That's it now there's nothing left which I can possibly provide since there's nothing else which could have any kind of affect on the telerik grid so if there is still something else  which might be hidden some place else that I may be missing then please explain what that might be since the only thing I haven't included is the code to do with the Create and Edit pages but all they involve is making each simple record then allowing the user to change the dates recorded.

Comment: wonder if the title isn't accurate enough or just that this is too complex a problem to solve quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what I tried to do from the start

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult _List(int? Id)
{
    List<...DTO> ret = new List<...DTO>();
    _db.(...).ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        ret.Add(new ...DTO
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.(...)Name,
            C1D = (x.C1SD.HasValue) ? x.C1SD.Value.ToShortDateString() : "",
            C2D = (x.C2SD.HasValue) ? x.C2SD.Value.ToShortDateString() : "",
```

Trick is to do all the calculations in the controller and leave the model and view very basic.

Model- left em all as string and basically did `public string blah { get; set;}` for each date col and then for each col you want to do something complex like my date calculations you would make an additional col, this would be for the colour/whatever feature you want heck you could even setup an admin function so if they don't have win auth or aren't in correct role etc then it would splarf the data or de-link a url link.

Controller- well as you can see above thats how I sorted out the dates showing up and now the surprisingly simple way to sort out the colour or w/e, (example thing `blahDTO bdt = new blahDTO();` )

```
if (x.TestVal1 != null)
                {
                    if ((x.TestVal1) > (DateTime.Today.AddMonths(6)))
                    {
                        bdt.Colourflag1 = "green";
                    }
```

Now it doesn't have to be green, it could be true false tom dick or jane w/e but it would just have to be a value assigned based on certain unique conditions.

View- when I realised it could be this easy I facepalmed myself, anyway yeh so `c.Bound(x => x.Colourflag1).Hidden(true);` next step

```
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("onRowDataBound"))
<script type="text/javascript">
   function onRowDataBound(e) {

           if (e.dataItem.TestVal1 == "green") {

               e.row.cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
```

and hey presto you just turn the 1st row/col cell green and this can be twisted and used into w/e e.row.cell[?]. can be used for and you have a single cell do all magic ye ha rolled into 1.

Now I know my jscript code is wasteful since I'm sure at this point you could make the green be an object which would then affect the the next object so if yellow then it makes the background colour code fit in yellow.

If anybody has any questions or jscript advice feel free to ask/comment.

Answer (score 1):

Edit 3 :

When you do :

When you do _db.(...).ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            ret.Add(new ...DTO
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.(...)Name,
                C1D = (x.C1SD.HasValue) ? x.C1SD.Value.ToShortDateString() : "",
                C2D = (x.C2SD.HasValue) ? x.C2SD.Value.ToShortDateString() : "",
            }
        }

x would be the ObjectFromDB, you don't want to assign each properties of the DTO, you want to pass the baseObject (witch is x), then return the value you want from x.

If you can provide me with youre solution using putfile or something else I can take a look at it if you want to but right now I don't know how it would be possible to help you more than that...

End Edit 3

Can you put some code?

I'll go with solution 1.

You could add a css class to a  using ClientTemplate, if it's > [timespan], I think that you should add a colum that is bound on a property that could return name of a css class or an empty string depending on the time span. Let say you have a DateCol1 property witch is a DateTime you could add a DateCol1Css property that goes like this :

```
public string DateCol1Css
    {
        get
        {
            if(DateCol1 < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)) return "Color1"; //witch is less than a month
            if(DateCol1 < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)) return "Color2"; //witch is less than 3 months
            if(DateCol1 < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)) return "Color3"; //witch is less than 6 months
            return  "";
        }
    }

    public string DateCol2Css
    {
        get
        {
            if (DateCol2 < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10)) return "Color1"; //witch is less than 10 days
            if (DateCol2 < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)) return "Color2"; //witch is less than 30 days
            return "";
        }
    }

    public string DateCol3Css
    {
        get
        {
            if (DateCol3 < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)) return "Color1"; //witch is less than a month
            if (DateCol3 < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)) return "Color2"; //witch is less than 3 months
            if (DateCol3 < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)) return "Color3"; //witch is less than 6 months
            return "";
        }
    }
```

And the grid should be like this :

```
    <%= Html.Telerik().Grid<SerializableAdmin>()
                        .Name("Grid")
                        .Columns(colums =>
                         {
                             colums.Bound(c => c.FirstName);
                             colums.Bound(c => c.Id);
                             colums.Bound(c => c.Id).ClientTemplate("<span class=\"<#=DateCol1Css#>\"<#=DateCol1#></span>");
colums.Bound(c => c.Id).ClientTemplate("<span class=\"<#=DateCol2Css#>\"<#=DateCol2#></span>");
colums.Bound(c => c.Id).ClientTemplate("<span class=\"<#=DateCol3Css#>\"<#=DateCol3#></span>");

                         })
                %>
```

**Edit :**

Take a look at this code, you pass the object from the database to your new object and add property with get only on the db object.

```
public class ObjectDTO
{
    public ObjectFromDB BaseObject { get; set; }

    public int Id 
    {
        get { return BaseObject.Id; }
    }

    public string Name 
    {
        get { return BaseObject.Name; }
    }


    public string C1D
    {
        get
        {
            if (BaseObject.C1SC.HasValue && BaseObject.C1SC < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-183)) return "Green";
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public string C2D
    {
        get
        {
            if (BaseObject.C2SC.HasValue && BaseObject.C2SC < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-183)) return "Green";
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
[GridAction]
public ActionResult _List(int? Id)
{
    List<ObjectDTO> ret = new List<ObjectDTO>();
    _db.GetObjectFromDB().ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        ret.Add(new ObjectDTO { ObjectFromDB = x } );
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't have any of it coded yet because I have no clue where to start with it depending on whats do-able via the help I get here, in regards to your duedate well I would also need to be able to set that any date recorded in each of the 6 fields would then record 3 additional dates for the relevant cols and then someone get the duedate to work in a telerik grid and look at each of those dates from the expired up as to which colour to display? if something like that then I'd still need to know to go about it, anyway off for weekend so cya monday.

Comment: So no more help or did you just forget about this topic?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you try to do... what is youre problem, maybe you can try to do it then bring some code so I will be able to help you, still I added some more code and I hope it will help you, let me know.

Comment: I explained the 3 possible solutions to my problem in my question, the overall objective is to record on a record date submissions so say for example a new product comes out and it needs like 5 different safety checks which have different lengths of renewal, now for each check the user would submit a date and depending on the check as mentioned some would be of different renewal lengths but all would follow the same guidelines, more than 6months left would display that check as colour1, more than 1month = colour2 etc to colour 4 this would be solution 1 to have it all on same grid.

Comment: Then as explained in my question there are 2 other solutions to this depending on if sol 1 is feasible, I hope this clears things up, in regards to the code well 1st this is the 2nd project on my list of todo's and so goes onto point 2, 2nd I have no clue how to go about implementing this other than thinking up the 3 most likely solutions I'm unsure what is possible hence this question to find someone who does know and who would be willing to guide me through the steps I would need to take, so any guidance/help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ok I eddited my answer. Solution 1 is feasible and you have the code on how to do it.

Comment: thx, I'll prob be starting on this project either this week or the next so if all goes well I'll mark this as the answer or I'll be getting bk to u, in the mean time I've +1 this answer.  Only other thing would be that for each datetime input I set it to record the renewal date AddYears ranging from 1-4 based of each check.

Comment: I hope I'm getting this right, I would program this in a Model which for me I'm using a DTO setup just for the telerik grid, if I was to follow exactly your solution I would then get 2 errors, 1 for not using set; since I would typically code public string C2D { get; set; } for example and if I add set; then I get rid of this error, 2nd error is it would say "Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DateTime'" so I tried[ get
            {
                if ((C1D = DateTime.ParseExact(C1D, "yyyy/mm/dd", null)) < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-183)) return "Green";

Comment: }
            set;]  and then I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'sting'" so any ideas or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'll test out this code asap but that might not be for a couple days now since my previous project is soon reaching piloting stage and yesterday I got some feedback from end-users for new features and changes so this project will be put on hold till that's ready.  Hopefully it won't take me too long to implement whats needed and I can get bk into this and finish it.

Comment: What "using ..." do I need to use in order to use BaseObject and "GetObjectFromDB"?

Comment: You need to use your object "..." I replace the ... to be more readable.

Comment: I still don't understand what your refering to, I've already replaced ObjectDTO with the name of the DTO I'm using but I don't know what Base... and Get...FromDB could be replaced with if it needs to or otherwise what Using I would need to have in my code in order to get the BaseObject etc to work?

Comment: When you do _db.(...).ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            ret.Add(new ...DTO
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.(...)Name,
                C1D = (x.C1SD.HasValue) ? x.C1SD.Value.ToShortDateString() : "",
                C2D = (x.C2SD.HasValue) ? x.C2SD.Value.ToShortDateString() : "",

Comment: Ok vinny from the looks of that you want me to put in the Database table name instead of BaseObject which if that is the case it doesn't get me into the table since I get 4 options after the "." which are "Create...", "EntityKeyPropertyName", "Equals" and "ReferenceEquals".

Otherwise if I use _db.(...). then that also doesn't get me into the table so can you please go into detail as to what I'm meant to be using/typing?

Comment: give me your email so you can send me code because I just can't help you more than that... I want to but I can't.

Comment: Is it not something you can post on SO? and in regards to sending you more code well I've pretty much sent you already all the code which is involved in this, this project isn't to complex it just adds new records with a string label and 6x dates then has a list page to display all records and need to display the dates/cells in different colours so the user can easily spot which record and area needs attention.  Either way I'll look at my project and edit my question with any additional code which seems even slighty relevant with ofc obsuring/replacing the identifying names.

Comment: added in everything else which could of had any involvement with the list page/telerik grid.

Answer (score 0):

For this code block, have you try to cast the string in datetime?

```
    .CellAction(cell =>
{
    if (cell.Column.Title == "Title Name")
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.DataItem.C1D) && DateTime.ParseExact(cell.DataItem.C1D, "yyyy/mm/dd", null) > DateTime.Today.AddDays(183))
        {
            //Set the background of this cell only
            cell.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "background:red;";
        }
    }
})
```

And your ...Dto property for the CssColor should be like this :

```
public class ...DTO
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string C1D
        {
            get
            {
                if (!C1SD.HasValue) return string.Empty;
                return (DateTime.ParseExact(C1SD, "yyyy/mm/dd", null) < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-183)) ? "Green" : "";
            }
        }
}
```

So your GridAction would be like this :

```
[GridAction]
    public ActionResult _List(int? Id)
    {
        List<...DTO> ret = _db.(...).ToList();
 ...
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Coding the CellAction bit has no problem only issue is http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/cellaction-doesn-t-seem-to-work.aspx which was posted in dec 2009 and indicated it only works with server-side whether thats still the case I don't know but as u can see from my code it's ajax, bk to the rest of it and more or less everything in the DTO works cept because the _list action has problems I had to replace if (!C1SD.HasValue) with (C1SD == null) but yeh I think this is due to the _list with me not knowing what I should do with everything after ToList();

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(Database Name).Models.(Table Name)>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(Database Name).Models.DTO.(DTO Name)DTO> is the error I get if I follow exactly how you put it well with ofc putting in the actual names

Comment: @VinnyG any other ideas or solutions? also in case it helps I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to program all this

Comment: I don't know what I can explain you more than that but if you send me your code I can take a look...

Comment: well I'll check to see what else I haven't already posted up but my point is most of it now is similar if not exactly like what you suggested trying, still at least 1 thing I have to fall bk to is server-side instead of ajax and then I'd just have to figure out what I would need to change to make that so and then I can use cellaction. Unfortunately I've been given another more important project to work on so this one is being put on hold again, I'll get bk to you with w/e else I can asap.

Comment: and my point is that if you send me your code I will be able to debug I find a solution without having to write 23 more post here :P It is possible to do, you are probably facing more problem than I think of but with the solution I could do it easyly...

Comment: Resolved it all in the controller and tricked the grid into displaying what it needed, I'll try and post up l8r today exactly how I got it to work.

Comment: Good I knew you could do it, hope my code helps you get the solution!

Comment: the cellaction might of if I was using server side binding but then again even then I found out the free telerik grid has a bug which causes problems getting a single cell to change colour or maybe even just simply to only affect a single cell with w/e affect desired, took a while before the telerik support guy I spoke to found that out and believed what I was telling him.